# Error in sql connector configuration when connecting using Ballerina MYSQL Client

Tags: mysql, wso2, ballerina

I'm trying to comment using Ballerina Mysql client.(Ballerina version - 0.990.2 ,MySQL JDBC driver-5.1.6) But I'm getting error as

> error: error in sql connector configuration:Failed to initialize pool: Unknown initial character set index '255' received from server. Initial client character set can be forced via the 'characterEncoding' property.:Unknown initial character set index '255' received from server. Initial client character set can be forced via the 'characterEncoding' property. {}

```
 mysql:Client testDB = new({
            host: "localhost",
            port: 3306,
            name: "users",
            username: "root",
            password: "password",
            poolOptions: { maximumPoolSize: 5 },
            dbOptions: { useSSL: false }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution for the error. This is due to the mismatch in the mysql version and MySQL connector version. I downloaded the suitable version from http://central.maven.org/maven2/mysql/mysql-connector-java/